# How to show git branch name on Header using php

Tags: php, git, git-branch

I need to show the branch name on the top of the Navigation bar.
Can anybody know how to show it?
I am using Laravel so tried this.

```
@php
  $rev = exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD');
  echo $rev;
@endphp
```

Please provide me the appropriate options.

Comment: `git branch` to get current branch name

Comment: Try the function `__git_ps1`. If it works, you may need to remove the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exec function can be a bit tricky and hold many unforseen problems if your not sure where to start. First, the process executing the function is usually under the _www user not your users account on your computer. This would imply that not all programs will be directly accessible via the PATH enviromantal configuration. Secondly, I have found that the output of some programs gets sent through standard error for no apparent reason.

An example of case 2 would be

```
$output = `nc -z 127.0.0.1 {$port}`;
```

The [Backtick Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) will execute the bash script between using the **shell_exec()** fucntion and also print the full output unlike exec counterpart. Moving forward, I recomend you attach the **2>&1** command at the end of your script. This will print the error output as well as execution data.

```
$rev = `git rev-parse --short HEAD 2>&1`;
```

After you add this you may receive another error closer to theroy one:

```
sh: git: command not found
```

This is when you would need to add an exact execution path to the desired program. You can do this by using terminal (not in php CGI/GUI execution) and the which command

```
>> which git
/usr/bin/git
```

...

```
$rev = `/usr/bin/git rev-parse --short HEAD 2>&1`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commands shows the current branch Name in PHP

```
exec('git symbolic-ref HEAD', $output);
$branches = explode('/', $output[0]);
$branch = end($branches);
```

**and the second solution is**

```
$branch = trim(shell_exec('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'));
```